# How to take out the index of an array in a select tag?

Tags: php

I'm trying to add a year feature in my code.

Here, I push the years in an array, which can be selected after, using a select

```
    $years = 2020;
    $years_array = array();

    // up-to-date years in array, starting from year 2020
    while ($years <= date('Y'))
    {
        $to_push = array(strval($years)=>$years);
        array_push($years_array, $to_push);
        $years++;
    }
    $choices = array_values($years_array);
```

Then, I add them to the builder (I also show you the months, this has been developed by someone before me)

```
        ->add('mois', ChoiceType::class, [
        'choices'  => [
            'Janvier'   => 1,
            'Février'   => 2,
            'Mars'      => 3,
            'Avril'     => 4,
            'Mai'       => 5,
            'Juin'      => 6,
            'Juillet'   => 7,
            'Aout'      => 8,
            'Septembre' => 9,
            'Octobre'   => 10,
            'Novembre'  => 11,
            'Décembre'  => 12
        ],
        'data' => date('n')
    ])
    ->add('annee', ChoiceType::class, [
        'choices'  => $choices,
        'data' => date('Y')
```

It works fine, I get the year afterwards, and the text shows up in the Select tag.

But I see the indexes of the array, as shown in this picture, which looks terrible.

[image: this]

How could I take these off?

Answer (score 1):

You're nesting the associative arrays into an indexed array. You should just assign directly to indexes of `$years_array`.

```
for ($year = $years; $year < date('Y'); $year++) {
    $years_array[$year] = $year;
}
```

You don't need to use `array_values()` afterward.

Comment: Also they are using `array_values` after so its unclear whether they need the year as the index.

Comment: @AbraCadaver It's not clear they really need to use that. In this case it has no effect since the array isn't associative.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I -think I- really need an associative array though, since it uses the same template as the months.

Comment: This is an associative array. It uses `$year` as both the key and value.